# pandas dataframe apply function to columns with nans

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, nan, statsmodels

I have a large pandas dataframe with many time series of different lengths which looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', periods=30, freq='Q'),
                   'series1': range(30), 
                   'series2': range(30), 
                   'series3': range(30)}).set_index('date')

df.loc[:11, 'series1'] = np.nan
df.loc[:6, 'series2'] = np.nan
```

I want to apply a statistical filter from statsmodels on each time series but the modul can't handle missing values and returns a dataframe full of NaNs.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
df_cycles, df_trend = sm.tsa.filters.cffilter(df, low=6, high=40)
```

Is there a clean way to apply the function to each column individually starting from the first non-nan observations?
I don't want to exclude the rows with missing values.

Comment: Why don't you want to exclude rows with NaN values? That is the correct thing to do unless you have a way to fill the NaN values correctly.

Comment: But why should I exclude rows if I want to apply the filter and do transformations to each time series individually. If I were to exclude all series with nans, the time series in the original dataframe would be much shorter and a lot of information would be lost.

Comment: What do you expect to filter on NaNs? You can apply the filter by column otherwise, so you keep the max valuable data for each column. Still, for NaNs, or you fill them with something or you drop them.

Comment: Have you checked https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html ?

Comment: Applying the filter by column is what I mean. Applying the filter from the first non-nan observation per column. Fill them is also not an option as it might change the statistical properties of the time series.

Comment: check my answer, I hope to have guessed correctly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the filter for each column, and store the result in some object. In this case I am making a dictionary with the column name as the key and the cycles and a dataframe containing trend and results as the value.

```
filtered = {}
for c in df.columns:
    cycles, trend = sm.tsa.filters.cffilter(
        df[c].astype(float).dropna(),
        low=6,
        high=40
    )
    filtered[c] = pd.DataFrame({'cycles':cycles, 'trend':trend})


print(filtered['series1'])

#                  cycles  trend
#date                           
#2015-12-31  8.881784e-16   11.0
#2016-03-31  6.661338e-16   11.0
#...


print(filtered['series3'])

#            cycles  trend
#date                     
#2013-03-31     0.0    0.0
#2013-06-30     0.0    0.0
#...
```

As you can see, for each column, the rows containing NaNs were dropped without affecting the other columns.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574658/missing-observations-and-clustered-standard-errors-in-python-statsmodels) thread might be useful to you. Typically statsmodels have a 'missing' keyword, but as detailed in the linked previous StackOverflow answer, this isn't always the case. The author of the post proposed this solution:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

available_data = all_data.loc[:,['y', 'x', 'groupid']].dropna(how='any')
model  = smf.ols('y ~ x', data = available_data)
```

Which produces no error when used with your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', periods=30, freq='Q'),
                   'series1': range(30),
                   'series2': range(30),
                   'series3': range(30)}).set_index('date')

df.loc[:11, 'series1'] = np.nan
df.loc[:6, 'series2'] = np.nan

# Change here
available_data = df.dropna(how="any")

import statsmodels.api as sm
df_cycles, df_trend = sm.tsa.filters.cffilter(available_data, low=6, high=40)
```

Comment: This solution does not solve my problem. I only have NaNs at the beginning of the time series due to the different start times. The filter should be applied individually for each time series, but this is not possible due to the NaNs at the beginning.